# Spring XML config to JavaConfig: inheritance and bean dependency

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

I have a list of services that extend an AbstractService class. The AbstractService holds the DAO (you can call it "repository") and has the getter/setter for the DAO:

```
/**
 * @param <T> Entity type
 * @param <K> Entity ID type
 * @param <S> DAO type
 */
public abstract class AbstractService<T, K extends Serializable, S extends BaseDAO<T, K>> implements BaseService<T, K> {
    private S dao;

    public S getDAO() { return dao; }

    public void setDAO(S dao) { this.dao = dao; }

    // Then common methods to all my services, using the DAO, for instance

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findOne(K key) throws DataException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(dao.findOne(key));
    }
}
```

A service example:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl extends AbstractService<Employee, Integer, EmployeeDAO> implements EmployeeService {
    // Some specific methods to that service
}
```

The related DAO (I use Spring Data JPA):

```
public interface EmployeeDAO extends BaseDAO<Employee, Integer> {
}
```

Extending

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseDAO<T, K extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, K> {
}
```

By the way I added the annotations `@Service` and `@NoRepositoryBean` while moving to JavaConfig.
My old XML config was:

```
<bean id="com.xxx.service._AbstractService" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="com.xxx.dao._TxManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-com.xxx.DataException</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-com.xxx.DataException</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-com.xxx.DataException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="com.xxx.service.EmployeeService" parent="com.xxx.service._AbstractBO">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.xxx.service.EmployeeServiceImpl">
            <property name="DAO" ref="com.xxx.dao.EmployeeDAO"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**First question, what is the proper way to inject the generic DAO and handle the service inheritance using JavaConfig?

Second question, how to translate the XML snippet about transactions (com.xxx.service._AbstractBO) to JavaConfig?**

Here is what I have so far, 2 classes:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.service")
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

And the persistence config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxx.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {
    /* Here so far I defined the DataSource, the EntityManagerFactory,
       the PlatformTransactionManager and the JpaVendorAdapter */
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Don't try to convert the transaction code, move to `@Transactional` instead.  Annotate your `@Service` with `@Transactional` and add `@EnableTransactionManagement` and well assuming you already have a transaction manager that is all you need.

Comment: Ok thanks, indeed I have seen such code. Should I do it only on the abstract service class or every class extending it should also have the annotation? If it's at the class level, does that mean all method will be transactional or I also have to annotate each method that needs to be transactional?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing: instead of trying to translate my old XML config, I changed the classes design. Since DAOs are required anyway, I inject them in each concrete class constructor which calls a new abstract class constructor I added.

The abstract service:

```
final private S dao;

public AbstractService(S dao) {
    super();
    this.dao = dao;
}

// getter protected and setter removed
protected S getDAO() {
    return dao;
}
```

And a concrete service example:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl extends AbstractService<Employee, Integer, EmployeeDAO> implements EmployeeService {

    @Inject
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeDAO dao) {
        super(dao);
    }
}
```

The good thing is I didn't have to change the Java config I posted in my question, meaning `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxx.repository")` and `@ComponentScan("com.xxx.service")` are sufficient to generate and bind beans.